# Flash CS5 code hinting not working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

code hinting doesn't seem to work for my Flash CS5. I already tried [increasing the code hint cache size](http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=2002), but it still doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code hinting usually works for me on most projects, but occasionally it stops, I'm still working on the reason for my occasional problem.  nothing conclusive yet.  but when it was not working it wasn't even working for the normal flash classes which was a bother.

here are some more ideas from some blog.

http://flashthusiast.com/2010/06/04/tips-for-code-hints-in-flash-cs5/

I haven't tried these yet.

Answer (score 1):

is Code Hints activated in your Preferences?
[image]

it probably is, but i had to ask.

this happens to me sometimes, usually when i start a new ActionScript File or ActionScript 3.0 Class from the New Document menu.  when it happens i have to save and reopen my file in order to see code hinting.

Comment: Yes, that's activated, but it was worth checking. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it happens alot when I **haven´t specified the object** I´m trying to do stuff to. If AS doesn´t know what kind of object it is dealing with (int, string, event, function, button, array, movieclip etc) it can't give you any hints.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but for anyone else with this issue, here is how I got it working again. Originally, I was opening the .fla and the .as at the same time. But when I closed out of flash, and opened JUST the .fla and then the .as, code hinting now works. I hope this helps.